# Медленный вывод символов в консоли

Tags: python, python-3.x

Стала интересная одна вещь, но не знаю как такое сделать.
Как при запуске программы которая выводит, к примеру, тот же "Hello World", выводить каждый символ с задержкой, а не моментальное его появление, как мы привыкли видеть

Comment: `for x in 'Hello World': print(x, flush=True); time.sleep(1)`

Comment: @andreymal можно еще `end=""` добавить для изящности), Вот еще [видос](https://vk.com/video-72495085_456239119?list=74167136daf2f13d97) (правда нормального написанного кода нету)

Comment: @Twiss добавил, спасибо)

Comment: @andreymal а можно ли исправить подлагивание при выводе? если поставить 0,1 скорость, то будет выводить по 2 символа

Comment: @daedra это не пролагивания это задержка программы на 1 секунду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time
s = 'hello'
for i in s:
   print (i)
   time.sleep(1)
```